# Problem with negative dimensions in CNN hyperparameter optimization

Tags: optimization, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters, optuna

When optimizing CNN hyperparameters in Optuna, they are sometimes set so that an error occurs when building the resulting model:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "max_pooling1d_2" (type MaxPooling1D). Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for...

This is the part of the code where I optimize the convolutional layers

```
model = keras.Sequential(name = "Model")

    model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((INPUT_DIMS, 1),input_shape = (INPUT_DIMS,)))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = trial.suggest_int("filters_1", 1, 50), 
                                  kernel_size = trial.suggest_int("kernel_size_1", 2, 70),
                                  strides = trial.suggest_int("strides_1", 2, 50),
                                  padding = "same",
                                  activation = activation_function,
                                  input_shape = (INPUT_DIMS,1)))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
    
    num_conv = trial.suggest_int("Num_Conv_layer", 0, 3)

    for i in range(num_conv):
          model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = trial.suggest_int(f"filters_{i+2}", 1, 50), 
                                        kernel_size = trial.suggest_int(f"kernel_size_{i+2}", 2, 70),
                                        strides = trial.suggest_int(f"strides_{i+2}", 2, 50),
                                        padding = "same",
                                        activation = activation_function))
          
          model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
```

Couldn't I modify the code somehow to prevent this error from occurring?